# Build gnome-shell issue: jhbuild does not find libtiff

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, jhbuild

I started tinkering with gnome-shell to kill time and I just can't get `jhbuild` to work! I followed all the instructions on the [`jhbuild` guide](https://wiki.gnome.org/Newcomers/BuildGnome) on the [gnome-shell wiki](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Development).

I got to the part where it says to run `$ jhbuild sysdeps gnome-shell`.

```
txjoe@superpotato:~$ jhbuild sysdeps gnome-shell
System installed packages which are new enough:
    libvpx (vpx.pc, installed=1.4.0)
    speex (speex.pc, required=1.2rc1, installed=1.2rc1)
    ruby 
    libtool 
    libtool-ltdl 
    [...]
    gmime (gmime-2.6.pc, required=2.6.6, installed=2.6.20)
    docbook-xml 
    mtdev (mtdev.pc, required=1.1.1, installed=1.1.5)
Required packages:
  System installed packages which are too old:
    (none)
  No matching system package installed:
    libsystemd-journal (libsystemd-journal.pc, required=201)
    libtiff 
    poppler (poppler-glib.pc, required=0.24.0)
Optional packages: (JHBuild will build the missing packages)
  System installed packages which are too old:
    libical (libical.pc, required=1.0.1, installed=1.0)
    WebKit (webkit2gtk-4.0.pc, required=2.11.3, installed=2.8.5)
  No matching system package installed:
```

I installed the following packages manually

```
libsystemd-dev 
python-poppler
libtiff5
python-libtiff
```

And I got the same output when I ran the same command again.
I checked other answers here, nothing seems to work so far. Any tips?

Comment: UPDATE : i was able to fix poppler , by looking for poopler.pc using apt-file search , but the same approach isn't working for the rest of the problems ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the *development* packages. It is possible that you installed the *runtime* libraries, but those ones do not have the header files to compile a program.

The development libraries in Debian-based distributions end in *-dev*. Thus, installing `libtiff5` is not enough, because it is the *runtime* library.

In your specific case, you must install `libtiff5-dev`, `libpoppler-glib-dev`, and `libsystemd-dev`.

Alternatively, you can try:

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep gnome-shell
```

This command will install the development libraries required to build `gnome-shell`. At least, this might help to start with, and fix the particular issues/